# ImportError: No module named 'Queue'

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to import `requests` module, but I got this error
my python version is 3.4 running on ubuntu 14.04

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 10, in <module>
    from queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
ImportError: cannot import name 'LifoQueue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
   from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
ImportError: No module named 'Queue'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I solve the problem my issue was I had file named queue.py in the same directory

Comment: Helped me. It's embarassing but I've created my own custom queue.py file to learn queues. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Is there a way to import the real module without naming the local `queue.py`?

Answer (score 172):

`import queue` is **lowercase** `q` in Python 3.

Change `Q` to `q` and it will be fine.

(See code in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688081/632951 for smart switching.)

Comment: This is relevant to people explicitly importing `Queue`, but the OP's traceback makes it clear the `requests` module is trying `queue` first, then falling back to try `Queue`  (making it version portable exactly as described). You're answering the question a lot of people having this error have, but not the OP's question at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm guessing the code failed for OP because the 3.x-specific version (tried first) didn't provide the appropriate names, in turn because it imported `queue.py` from OP's own project rather than the standard library - as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353 .

Comment: Ah, I scrolled down and found the OP's own answer, which confirmed my suspicion. This is a dupe, then, and a very misleading one. It should be scrubbed. A shame it got 286k views.

Answer (score 61):

Queue is in the multiprocessing module so:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Comment: I don't know why this python comed without it. The good replacement for queue.Queue is multiprocessing.JoinableQueue, because allows to simply replace the import without have to edit .join() and .task_done() flow.

Comment: The `multiprocessing.Queue` is a completely different class with a *lot* higher overhead; for threading, you *want* `Queue` from the `queue`(Py3)/`Queue`(Py2) module. `requests` is correctly trying to get it from both names (so it's version agnostic); the failure indicates a completely different problem (as the OP explains in their answer).

Comment: Also, since `multiprocessing.Queue` is pickling based, it's not even functionally equivalent; if you have non-picklable objects getting passed between threads, it will succeed with `queue`/`Queue`'s `Queue` class, and fail with `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Answer (score 31):

It's because of the Python version. In Python 2.x it's `import Queue as queue`; on the contrary in Python 3 it's `import queue`. If you want it for both environments you may use something below as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363871/no-module-named-queue?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
try:
   import queue
except ImportError:
   import Queue as queue
```

Comment: You made typo. You should change to this:In Python 3 it's `import queue`; on the contrary in Python2.x it's `import Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it should be:

`from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue`

Since in python2, Queue has methods like `.task_done()`, but in python3 `multiprocessing.Queue` doesn't have this method, and `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` does.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem and learn that queue module defines classes and exceptions, that defines the public methods (Queue Objects).

Ex.

```
workQueue = queue.Queue(10)
```

Answer (score -2):

I just copy the file name Queue.py in the `*/lib/python2.7/` to queue.py and that solved my problem.