# no module named 'Queue' on windows

Tags: python, queue

I try use a program on windows:

```
import random, time, Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

task_queue = Queue.Queue()
result_queue = Queue.Queue()

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

QueueManager.register('get_task_queue', callable=lambda: task_queue)
QueueManager.register('get_result_queue', callable=lambda: result_queue)

manager = QueueManager(address=('', 5000), authkey='abc')
manager.start()
task = manager.get_task_queue()
result = manager.get_result_queue()

for i in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0, 10000)
    print('Put task %d...' % n)
    task.put(n)
print('Try get results...')

for i in range(10):
   r = result.get(timeout=10)
   print('Result: %s' %r)
manager.shutdown()
```

I get an ERROR:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Queue'
```

But I run it in the Ubuntu, It works.
 I search Queue in the stackoverflow,pypi.python.org for windows and try pip install Queue. Finally it failed.So how I use the Queue  module on the windows?

Comment: In Python3 the module is named `queue` (lowercased).

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432426/importerror-no-module-named-queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use `Queue` from multiprocessing module, then import this way -

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

If you want to use the queue data structure, then you use lowercased `queue`.

```
import queue
```

Comment: was just about to write this, beat me to it